# Angular - ui grid - fonts

Tags: css, angularjs, fonts, gruntjs, angular-ui-grid

i installed "angular" and "angular-ui-grid" in my app and included nessesary files:

```
angular.min.js
ui-grid.min.js
ui-grid.min.css
```

The table display´s properly, but the arrows in the row head are displayed as "korean symbols".

Anybody knows how do deal with this?
i followed these instructions exactly:

```
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro
```

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ui-grid.woff, ui-grid.ttf and ui-grid.svg. More info is on this page http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/116_fonts_and_installation

Comment: Seems they have updated their documentation. Here is the new link http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20116%20Fonts%20and%20Installation

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply moving `ui-grid.min.css` into the master page of my project.

Do not put `ui-grid.min.css` or if you're using the non minified version in the bundler.

This is how I solved this, no hard coding or re-routing.

1 library not getting bundled wont kill your project.